# Multiple data insertion into database from grid view

Tags: c#

I already have some data into the grid view. Now I want to insert multiple rows into gridview then how to do it?

If I go for foreach loop then it will take count of all the rows already there and insert the data multiple times. Instead I want to into new rows only

Below is my Code

```
    private void userInsert()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add the new  data ?", "Confirm ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            try
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow dRow in userDataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into users(first_name,last_name,default_rate,default_location,spi_user_id,nickname) values('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4},'{5}')", userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), locationID2ComboBox.SelectedValue, userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Your data has been added successfully ", "Saved info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                userSelect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you did so far? Your codes !!

Answer (score 0):

Either keep track which rows were inserted (may be done using `Tag` property for example, or modify your SQL query to check if data is already present

```
if not exists (select top 1 * from users u where u.first_name = '{0}' and u.last_name = '{1}')
   insert into users(first_name,last_name,default_rate,default_location,spi_user_id,nickname) 
   values('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4},'{5}'
```

you may need more argument checks for uniqueness. Also I suggest using parameters with`SqlCommand`.

If you want use `Tag` property (only when it is `Winforms` project!):

```
foreach (GridViewRow dRow in userDataGridView.Rows)
{
    var check = dRow.Tag as bool? ?? false; //was row already processed?

    if (check)
    {
        continue;
    }

    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into users(first_name,last_name,default_rate,default_location,spi_user_id,nickname) values('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4},'{5}')", userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), locationID2ComboBox.SelectedValue, userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dRow.Tag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is user id and who generate it ?

If user id is 0 for new user its simple

```
foreach (GridViewRow dRow in userDataGridView.Rows)
                {
                  if(userDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[<user id index>]==0)
                       {
                        //add into DB 
                        }

                }
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event to add new record:

```
private void dataGridView1_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     //e.Row.Cells[0].Value <-- Use 'e.Row' argument to access the new row
}
```